# how to save a Date Time on DB with sqlflite?

Tags: database, flutter

I have a problem on how to save a DateTime on a data base with sqflite , so even if I change a page the date won't desapear, Could any one help me please ? Thank you .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRFxQ.png)

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to save one date, sqflite is overkill, take a look at [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences).

```
onPressed:  ()async{
final selectedDate= await selectTimePicker(context);
 SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await prefs.seString('date', '$selectedDate');
}
```

Comment: actually I need to save two dates , ( two diffrent buttons) , can I do it with shared prefences ?

Comment: Sure, just save them using two different keys and read them as`DateTime.parse(prefs.getString('date'))`

Comment: I'm new in Flutter development so I don't know how to do it , can I contact you to show you th code so you can help me please , it's for my end of studie's project and I am so ddesperate .?  Thank you

Comment: Just reformulate your question or add new ones. I do not remember how to create chats/rooms here in SO.